# Qt 5.x analog of relative layout?

Tags: c++, qt

I have custom widget with `paintEvent override`,
I want to place "scale plus" and "scale minus" buttons on this
custom widget. I want to place them if the left bottom corner of widget,
in 1㎝ from bottom and right. I can not find anything like `QRelativeLayout` in Qt.
If it exists, I just put two buttons inside `QVBoxLayout`, and put
`QVBoxLayout` inside `QRelativeLayout`.

What the proper way to solve this in Qt 5.x,
should I override `QWidget::resizeEvent`, or inherit `QLayout` and implement relative layout logic?

Comment: What have you *tried* so far? What have you researched? What does your current code look like?

Comment: any of the 2 methods are valid.

Comment: It's also not really clear what you want, so any the standard layouts might just work too.